Previewing PDF from Firebase storage using barteksc's pdf viewer
a starter here, i am creating a app where users can upload and download E books and notes.. I'm using Firebase as the only database.
to preview a pdf, using barteksc's PDF view, i am passing uri to
PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
pdfView.fromUri(lnk).load();

I can assure you that the URI is working fine, (when i click on uri, it opens the correct pdf on safari). But I can't understand why during runtime, the apps logs as:
load pdf error                                                                                                    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/athena-login-6ad52.appspot.com/o/pdf%2FAhhh.pdf-1711905313326.pdf?alt=media&token=2dbb6ecc-42ef-4ec5-a5f5-eb1dec0dd90f

eHow my firebase storage looks(Ignore those names pls)
The code i'm working on:
private void loadPdfIntoViewer(String pdfFileName) {
        // Get a reference to the Firebase Storage instance
        StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        Log.d(null, "loadPdfIntoViewer: Searching for pdf named: " + pdfFileName);
        // Construct a reference to the PDF file
        StorageReference pdfRef = storageRef.child("pdf/" + pdfFileName + ".pdf");
        Log.d(null, "loadPdfIntoViewer: found pdf, address: pdf/" + pdfFileName + ".pdf");

        // Fetch the download URL of the PDF file
        pdfRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String pdfUriString = uri.toString();
                Uri lnk = uri;
                Log.d(null, "onSuccess: URI = " + pdfUriString);
                // Load the PDF into PDFView using the retrieved URL
                PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
                pdfView.fromUri(lnk).load();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Handle any errors
                Log.e("PdfPreview", "Failed to fetch PDF URL: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

Here's the github link for the codes, (PdfPreview.java being the one I'm dealing with right now)

What does Log.d(null, "onSuccess: URI = " + pdfUriString); display in the logcat?

@AlexMamo it prints the URI which on clicked, opens up thr pdf.

If you get the correct URI, then what's the issue?

@AlexMamo, the issue is that even if the correct uri is coming, the pdfView is not showing the pdf
